# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC returns JSON formatted as string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I see that my `APIController` is returning a JSON but formatted as text, which means I have to parse it in client in order to manipulated it, and I want to avoid that.

I tried several things that are mentioned in this site and none worked.

What can I do?

Here is the controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var ordersList =  await _ordenExternaService.GetOrdenExternaCasos();

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(casos);

    return Ok(json);
}
```

Here is the Postman result:

```
"[{\"Id\":3,\"IdOrdenExterna\":9041,\"NroCaso\":null,\"Motivo\":\"Nombre y Apellido de envio Completo no coincide con el del titular de la Tarjeta\",\"FechaEnvio\":null,\"NroOrdenPublica\":\"187901-205292-1665\"}]"
```

Comment: it's because you are serilizing it twice....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are double encoding the return value. Your action should really be

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   var ordersList = await _ordenExternaService.GetOrdenExternaCasos();

   return Ok(ordersList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer too.

Comment: I will, I have to wait 5 minutes to do that.